# React Native bottom tab navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I have a question, connected with a bottom tab navigator in React Native.

Let assume that I have 6 screens, and I want to show only 5 in a bottom tab navigator.

```
<Screen
  name='Home'
  component={Home}
  options={{
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => getTabIcon({ focused, source: walletIcon }),
  }}
/>
```

and like these, 4 other screens too.

I also have another screen, which I don't want to show at Navigator, and it looks like this.

```
<Screen
  name='EasyCoins'
  component={EasyCoin}
/>
```

I also have tried to give an option property to my specific screen like this. But this does not work for me.

```
options={{
  tabBarVisible: false,
}}
```

I am using

```
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.9",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build the screen you don't want to show using the stack-navigator. In this case it will not appear in the tab bar and you can go to that page with any redirect.

You can have a look here -> https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/